# How do you reference the HTMLSelect object from VBA?

Tags: html, excel, vba

I am trying to reference the HTMLSelect object in VBA. Assuming I have a form on the html page and a select control named LB. I can't figure out why I get an error message using the code below.

```
Dim ieApp As InternetExplorer
Dim ieSelect As HTMLSelect
Dim iePage as HTMLDocument

Set ieApp = New InternetExplorer
ieApp.Visible = True
ieApp.navigate "C:\formA.html"

 Do Until ieApp.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Loop


Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:05"))

Set iePage = ieApp.document
Set ieSelect = iePage.forms(0).Item("LB")
```

Answer (score 0):

Hm, not sure, but have you the runat="server" on the  in formA.html?